# Windows Authentication in Bonobo GIT Reloads Login Page

Tags: git, bonobo

I'm having problem with Windows Authentication on my Bonobo GIT server. 
At first I used internal authentication. 
Works well.

Then I switched to Windows Authentication. 
Now when I login in the login screen reloads with the login name of the last successful internal account displayed.

I looked in the Bonobo log. The Windows authentication is successful.

Version 6.3.0.632

```
<add key="AuthenticationProvider" value="Windows" />
<add key="ImportWindowsAuthUsersAsAdmin" value="false" />
<add key="MembershipService" value="ActiveDirectory" />
<add key="ActiveDirectoryDefaultDomain" value="MyDomain.local" />
<add key="ActiveDirectoryBackendPath" value="~\App_Data\ADBackend" />
<add key="ActiveDirectoryMemberGroupName" value="My_group" />
<add key="ActiveDirectoryTeamMapping" value="Developers=MyDev_group" />
<add key="ActiveDirectoryRoleMapping" value="Administrator=MyAdmin_group" />
```

Comment: The same problem here. What protocol do you use: http or https? And what IIS version?

Comment: https 
though I tried both protocols
IIS version 10.0.0.14393.0